# Get Unix timestamp with C++

Tags: c++, unix, timestamp, uint

How do I get a `uint` unix timestamp in C++? I've googled a bit and it seems that most methods are looking for more convoluted ways to represent time. Can't I just get it as a `uint`?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

C++20 introduced a guarantee that [`time_since_epoch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch) is relative to the UNIX epoch, and [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch) gives an example that I've distilled to the relevant code, and changed to  units of seconds rather than hours:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
 
int main()
{
    const auto p1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 
    std::cout << "seconds since epoch: "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
                   p1.time_since_epoch()).count() << '\n';
}
```

---

Using C++17 or earlier, [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) is the simplest function - seconds since Epoch, which for Linux and UNIX at least would be the UNIX epoch.  Linux [manpage here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time).

The cppreference page linked above gives this [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
}
```

Comment: "Epoch" is of course the Unix eproch on Unix and Linux, but that's not universal.

Comment: Note that `std::chrono::seconds` [is defined as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) `duration</*signed integer type of at least 35 bits*/>`. So e.g. a 32-bit int might not be enough.

Comment: please change c++20 to c++11.

Comment: @socketpair: do you have any documentation to support the change?

Comment: Yes, by link you have provided - cppreference. Note, the function is supported since c++11

Comment: @socketpair: the function is supported since C++11, but it was originally relative to an unspecified epoch (cppreference just says "the clock's epoch").  Since C++20 it's been required to be relative to the UNIX epoch (0 UTC 1 Jan 1970).  This distinction isn't discussed on the cppreference page.

Answer (score 54):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(0);  // t is an integer type
    std::cout << t << " seconds since 01-Jan-1970\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `std::time()` gives you seconds since 1970. That's true on a lot of systems (POSIX and Windows, I believe), but it's not guaranteed by the language standard.

Answer (score 19):

The most common advice is wrong, you can't just rely on `time()`. That's used for relative timing: ISO C++ doesn't specify that `1970-01-01T00:00Z` is `time_t(0)`

What's worse is that you can't easily figure it out, either. Sure, you can find the calendar date of `time_t(0)` with `gmtime`, but what are you going to do if that's `2000-01-01T00:00Z` ? How many seconds were there between `1970-01-01T00:00Z` and `2000-01-01T00:00Z`? It's certainly no multiple of 60, due to leap seconds.

Comment: "How do I get a uint unix timestamp in C++?" - given - as you've said - you can call `gmtime()` later to get a readable representation of whatever that timestamp encodes, what functionality requested in the question isn't satisfied by `time()`, regardless of the reference date or suitability for interval calculations?

Comment: To get a **UNIX** timestamp on a non-UNIX system, you have to know the difference (in seconds) between the local epoch and `1970-01-01T00:00Z`. There's just no method which does that.

Comment: For some reason I got the impression the question was for code on a UNIX (or Linux etc) machine, but now I see where you're coming from.  Curious: have you found any actual system where time_t(0) wasn't 1970-01-01T00:00Z?  Would be but a couple minutes work to work out an offset on any given system (take the non-UNIX time_t(0) and get a time_t for it on a UNIX system), but thanks for explaining your concern.

Comment: For VS its UNIX time; MSDN states: The time function returns the number of seconds elapsed since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), according to the system clock.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx

Comment: @TonyD: IBM systems apparently are an exception. Not really a surprise since they were in the computer business well before 1-1-1970.

Answer (score 14):

As this is the first result on google and there's no C++20 answer yet, here's how to use std::chrono to do this:

```
#include <chrono>

//...

using namespace std::chrono;
int64_t timestamp = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

In versions of C++ before 20, system_clock's epoch being Unix epoch is a de-facto convention, but it's not standardized. If you're not on C++20, use at your own risk.

Comment: The epoch will be officially recognized in C++20:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system.overview

Answer (score 12):

I created a global define with more information:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
    
#define __FILENAME__ (__builtin_strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? __builtin_strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)    // only show filename and not it's path (less clutter)
#define INFO std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time_now), "%y-%m-%d %OH:%OM:%OS") << " [INFO] " << __FILENAME__ << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ") >> "
#define ERROR std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time_now), "%y-%m-%d %OH:%OM:%OS") << " [ERROR] " << __FILENAME__ << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ") >> "
    
static std::time_t time_now = std::time(nullptr);
```

Use it like this:

```
INFO << "Hello world" << std::endl;
ERROR << "Goodbye world" << std::endl;
```

Sample output:

```
16-06-23 21:33:19 [INFO] main.cpp(main:6) >> Hello world
16-06-23 21:33:19 [ERROR] main.cpp(main:7) >> Goodbye world
```

Put these lines in your header file.  I find this very useful for debugging, etc.

Comment: Why `#define` and not a function? Function would be more flexible, overloadable, more obvious hoe to use...

Comment: @Troyseph Because then `__FILE__``__FUNCTION__``__LINE__ ` would not work as intended.  This is a macro.

Comment: Fair enough! Shame there isn't a more modern alternative =]

Comment: To save some effort, you can use "%F %T" to replace "%y-%m-%d %OH:%OM:%OS".

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  unsigned long int sec= time(NULL);
  cout<<sec<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `time()` returns a result of type `time_t`, which can in principle be either signed, unsigned, or even floating-point. Why store the result in a `long int`? And why use `<sys/time.h>` rather than the standard `<time.h>`?

Comment: I understand but I think in any posix compliant OS both time.h & sys/time.h are present.

Also you are completely correct that time_t can be negative value too as it is represented as seconds elapsed from 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

Answer (score 5):

Windows uses a different epoch and time units: see 
[Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux)

What std::time() returns on Windows is (as yet) unknown to me (;-))

Comment: you're referencing filetime, which is handled differently than 'system time'

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, just convert nanoseconds to whatever you like, and convert uint64_t to whatever you like.

```
#include <chrono>
uint64_t unix_time()
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
    (
        std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
    ).count();
}
```