# How to get the International Date Time in the log file from format "1497322467"

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, logging

I am trying to read the log file for the application transition time and the format of the Date/Time is in this format in Windows C++ programming for the app transition exit time "1497322467".

Could someone help me on how to extract the date and time from this type of format on Windows using C++?

Comment: @Samuel - C++ programming language in Windows OS

Comment: Thanks Samuel.. I will check on this!!

Answer (score -3):

This looks like the unix time format. Try `date` on Linux.

Comment: C++ programming language in Windows OS

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012663/get-unix-timestamp-with-c

Comment: Thanks.. I will check on this!!