# Timestamp conversion using cplusplus

Tags: c++, datetime

I have a time in format of a time stamp : 1597909502 which when converted to normal time gives Thursday, August 20, 2020 1:15:02 PM.
But I wanted to take my system time and convert like above time stamp using c++

https://www.epochconverter.com/

I used the Above website for conversion but how can i do this using c++ , i.e converting my current system time to above time stamp

Comment: Did you try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012663/get-unix-timestamp-with-c) answer? Is it what you want?

Comment: Yup just the same thing using c++, like taking my current system time and converting it to timestamp like 1597909502  this

Comment: The link that @Enrico provided shows you how to do just that with C++20 and older.

Comment: @Enrico thanks it worked, sorry i missunderstood at first