# How to Convert String date to double in C++,

Tags: android, c++, c++11

I am getting String from server `11/07/2020 10:57:13` which I am converting to double value `1604723233`, however converted double value is less than actual value by 1 hour.

Below is how I am trying to convert...

```
double StringDateToDouble(string &strDate, string format)
{
    tm currentTime = CurrentTimeToTM();
    tm timeinfo;

    string strTimeZone = currentTime.tm_zone;

    strDate.append("");
    strDate.append(strTimeZone);
    strptime(strDate.c_str(), format.c_str(), &timeinfo);

    time_t timeInSec = mktime(&timeinfo);
    return static_cast<double>(timeInSec);
 }

tm CurrentTimeToTM()
{
 struct tm timeinfo = {0};
 time_t rawtime;
 rawtime = time(&rawtime);

 localtime_r(&rawtime, &timeinfo);
 return timeinfo;
}
```

What is the correct way? is anything missed here? Any suggetion is appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? Why do you need a `double` of a date? How is a date represented using a `double`?

Comment: The C++ standard does not guarantee that `time_t(0)` is `1970-01-01T00:00Z`. C++20 introduced a guarantee that `time_since_epoch` will be relative to the UNIX epoch.

Comment: By the way, there's no guarantee that [`std::time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) is an integer type, or that its value is a number of seconds since some epoch.

Comment: Is the date in your string DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: Oh, times off by exactly one hour sounds like a daylight savings issue.

Comment: Try this : https://wandbox.org/permlink/dgHrTPRBMx27M8zr. Run this on the same system you were running your earlier code as on the server the timezone may be different from yours. I noticed from your profile that you are from India. So, this code should give : `1604726833` as the output (`3600` (1hr) more than `1604723233`, i.e. what you were expecting) .

Comment: @brc-dd I tried `11/07/2020 12:59:22` and output was `1604721562` which online converter shows(https://www.timestampconvert.com) `11/7/2020, 9:29:22`

Comment: @Vijay it is because of difference in time zones. The response which you are getting from your server is in which time zone?

Comment: @brc-dd oh we are getting timezone as a IST

Comment: @Vijay  I had clearly written in my comment to run the code on your system, not on wandbox itself. Wandbox servers are located in Japan most probably that's why `std::mktime` is giving you different localtime. If your server sends time in IST then better use this code : https://wandbox.org/permlink/y9KJPXKoiuaQHY1o I have specified time zone here. So the local timezone of the system or say the app that you are building won't matter now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggested code:

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

const int IST = (5 * 60 + 30) * 60; // GMT+05:30 (in s)

double StringDateToDouble(std::string &&strDate,
                          std::string &&format = "%D %T") {
  std::tm tm;
  std::istringstream ss(strDate);
  ss >> std::get_time(&tm, format.c_str());
  return (std::mktime(&tm) - timezone) - IST;
}

int main() { std::cout << (long)StringDateToDouble("11/07/2020 12:59:22"); }
```

References:

1. [How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25037057/11613622)
2. [std::mktime and timezone info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157134/11613622)
3. [Get Unix timestamp with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6012663/11613622)

---

As mentioned in the second reference, `std::mktime(&tm) - timezone` will give time in GMT. Now since your server is sending responses in IST, you need to manually subtract that from it to get the time since the Epoch.

---

Note that it is not guaranteed by the C++ standard that `1970-01-01T00:00Z` is `std::time_t(0)`.

Citing from [`std::time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time):

> The encoding of calendar time in std::time_t is unspecified, but most systems conform to POSIX specification and return a value of integral type holding the number of seconds since the Epoch. Implementations in which std::time_t is a 32-bit signed integer (many historical implementations) fail in the year 2038.

Refer to the thread mentioned as reference 3 for more discussion on this.