# How to get Unix time in C++, similar to Python's "time.time()"

Tags: c++

When measuring elapsed time in Python, I use the following method.

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
nowTime = time.time() - startTime
```

I think this code gets UNIX time in seconds.

time.time() returns a Float Value such as this.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1541317313.336098
```

How can I use the same measurement technique in C++ as in Python?

I intend to use C++ in a WIndows 64-bit limited environment.

Comment: Step 1: Consult [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012671/20002417
This is a very similiar question with a really good answer.

Comment: More precisely: [getting current time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) and [getting unix timestamp from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch). And when peeking into first link: The example there is actually a bad one, for measuring time periods `system_clock` is not suitable as time might jump (e.g. due to DST changing); use `steady_clock` for such purposes instead!

Comment: Just to make it clear: since you're measuring a time **duration**, the **epoch** doesn't matter. "Unix time" is a shorthand for "time, with an epoch of 1-1-1970". These 1970 years cancel out in the `current_time - start_time` subtraction. If if you used 1CE as the epoch, that would cancel out the same.

Answer (score 2):

You're friend is [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) – and note: *not* [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) as it doesn't guarantee the clock advancing monotonically (consider e.g. DST changing!).

Then you can do:

```
auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

// work of which the duration is to be measured

auto duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime;
```

The difference is a [std::chrono::duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) object, which you now can retrieve the relevant information from in the desired granularity, e.g. as ms:

```
 auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();
```

Instead of casting, which simply cuts off the sub-units just like an integral cast cuts away the fractional part of a floating point value, [*rounding*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/round) is possible, too.

Side note: If `std::chrono::steady_clock` happens to lack sufficient precision there's still [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock), though it is not guaranteed that it is actually more precise than the former – and worse, might even be implemented in terms of `std::system_clock` (see notes there), so its use is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
double now = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Go here for details.

[www.epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/)